# Aggregate Spatial Search Results MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with point locations and a value for each for each document.

I have no issue running spatial queries and getting the results, however at times I am returning a massive number of results, 5+million.  What I need from this result is not the individual documents but a sum of the values from all those returned documents.  Obviously with 5+mil results this is too much to iterate through and it appears the aggregate function is what I can use.

I am using the PyMongo Python API for most of the work.

Can someone demonstrate to me how to use the aggregate function to sum the values of a spatial query?

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of MongoDB have very nice aggregation framework, [described in doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) with some really nice examples.

If oyu want more precise help — it would be nice to see your sample records and queries you're running.